# Howto upload multiple files with Spring Boot and test it with cURL

Tags: http, curl, file-upload, spring-boot

I have implemented a Controller to upload multiple files:

```
public class Image implements Serializable {
    private MultipartFile file;
    private Ingeger imageNumber;
    ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void handleFileUpload(@RequestBody Set<Image> images) {
   ...
}
```

I correctly checked the code using only *one* MultipartFile directly in the upload method using this command:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/upload -X POST -F 'file=@1.jpg;type=image/jpg' -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"
```

I need to extend it in three ways but don't know the correct syntax:

1. POST a collection of JSON items
2. Add the field "imageNumber" for each item
3. Most tricky part: add a file nested to each item

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved it using an Array instead of a Set with nested files.

Java:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void handleFileUpload(@RequestParam MultipartFile[] images, @RequestParam Integer[] numbers) {
   ...
}
```

cURL:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/upload -X POST \
-F 'files=@1.jpg;type=image/jpg' \
-F 'numbers=1' \
-F 'files=@2.jpg;type=image/jpg' \
-F 'numbers=2' \
-F 'files=@3.jpg;type=image/jpg' \
-F 'numbers=3'
```