# Send email with multiple attachments in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, email-attachments, multipart

I'm creating an api for sending email in Spring Boot. I can successfully send an attachment in email using the following api

```
@PostMapping("/send")
public void sendMail(@RequestParam(value = "receiver") String receiver,
        @RequestParam(value = "subject") String subject, @RequestParam(value = "content") String content,
        @RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile file) {
    mailService.send(receiver, subject, content, file);
}
```

But an email can have multiple attachments. So, using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971705/howto-upload-multiple-files-with-spring-boot-and-test-it-with-curl#38973811) as the reference, I updated my code to

```
@PostMapping("/send")
public void sendMail(@RequestParam(value = "receiver") String receiver,
        @RequestParam(value = "subject") String subject, @RequestParam(value = "content") String content,
        @RequestParam(value = "files", required = false) MultipartFile[] files) {
    mailService.send(receiver, subject, content, files);
}
```

With this in place, I can add multiple images from the Swagger UI

Update:
I get the following form in Swagger from which I can upload images

[image: Swagger UI form]

But when I submit the form, I found that the value in files is now null instead of an array of files.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try using List instead of array 

                   @RequestBody List<MultipartFile> files
and uploaded files as RequestBody  instead of RequestParam

Comment: @MebinJoe yes. Same result.

Comment: are you always getting null?

Comment: are you using HTTP POST. Also add enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: Tried this: `@RequestMapping(value = "/attachment", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
 public void upload(@RequestParam List<MultipartFile> files) {
  for (MultipartFile file : files) {
   System.out.println(file.getOriginalFilename());
  }
 }` and now I get CollectionsEmptyList in files

Comment: Try @RequestParam("files") List<MultipartFile> files instead of MultipartFile[] files

Comment: how do you upload files or how you hit the API. Using any API client or from browser ?

Comment: @MebinJoe I'm using the swagger ui. I've added a screenshot in the op.

Comment: @ShashikantSharma tried that as well but no luck.

Comment: You did a mistake in your second code snippet replace Request param name `files` with `files' . Example  `@RequestParam(value = "file", required = false)` 
 instead of `@RequestParam(value = "files", required = false)`.

Comment: I think this is a known issue with swagger. https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues/467, https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag/issues/845. Try latest version as a workaround

Comment: @KshitijBajracharya In your swagger UI for content value did you try  'multipart/form-data' ? Swagger supports file uploads sent with Content-Type: multipart/form-data. That is, your API server must consume multipart/form-data for this operation. Ideally this should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes I've added multipart/form-data with `@RequestMapping(value = "/send", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")` Even with that, the payload of my request when adding single MultipartFile is `content: asdasd
file: (binary)
receiver: asd@adasd.com
subject: aaa` whereas the payload when I'm passing an array of files is `content: asdasd
files: {},{}
receiver: asd@adasd.com
subject: aaa`

Answer (score 0):

As @MebinJoe mentioned, it was an issue with swagger. Couldn't solve the issue with swagger but ended up using Postman for testing the above piece of code. Multiple files were successfully attached and sent in email.

Comment: Please raise an issue in swagger Github and followup. Might get resolved in later versions as single file upload is working fine. Could you please mark my answer as useful. Thank you

Comment: One more thing. In the swagger UI, did you try setting  content string value as 'multipart/form-data'  ?

Comment: @MebinJoe, yes I tried 'multipart/form-data' but it still didn't work in swagger.