# Attaching images in a POJO

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to create an Online Shopping app with Spring and Spring Data Jpa.

The problem which I am facing is that when I want to attach multiple images (as multipart file) in the POJO itself but I'm not able to figure out.

Comment: please share more details with the code you can receive your POJO as `@RequestBody` and can get an image as a `@RequestParam` if you don't want to image in POJO

Comment: depending on your models and setup it might be easier to just send the data and store that then wait for a response and then send the images with the params in the path.

Comment: Standard practice is to store images on a server or maybe AWS S3 and then give image links in POJO.

Comment: try from this [Howto upload multiple files with Spring Boot...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38971705/howto-upload-multiple-files-with-spring-boot-and-test-it-with-curl) . you will have a basic idea.